# Bootstrap Navbar Highlighting in Thymeleaf's layout

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am evaluating spring boot + MVC + bootstrap . One problem I am facing is bootstrap's navbar highlighting problem in thymeleaf.

I hope thymeleaf can judge the tab which should be highlighted.

I searched and found this solution : [Bootstrap Navbar Highlighting in Thymeleaf](http://nixmash.com/java/bootstrap-navbar-highlighting-in-thymeleaf/)

In the containing(outer) page , it uses

```
<div th:replace="header::header('home')">
  to be replaced header
</div>
```

to designate the `home` tab should be highlighted.

And in the contained (inner) page , it uses

```
<nav class="..." th:fragment="header(activeTab)">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li th:class="${activeTab == 'home'} ? 'active' : null "><a href="#" th:href="@{/home}">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

to judge this tab should be highlighted or not.

It works for **every single page** well , **but not for layout**.

In a layout page , the containing (outer) page is a decorator , which decorates other pages (home / about / contact ...) . The tab value is pending here .

for example

```
<div th:replace="header::header('home')">
  to be replaced header
</div>
<div layout:fragment="content">
  layout
</div>
<div th:replace="footer::footer">
  to be replaced footer
</div>
```

I cannot pre-assign `home` tab in the layout file.
Is there any way to solve it ?

Can it judge by controller or even controller's method ?

environment :

```
springboot.version 1.3.0.M5
spring.version :4.2.1.RELEASE
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a exact solution for your question but maybe you will like the idea. You may use request context path to recognize which tab is actually selected, so you can use `${#httpServletRequest.getContextPath()}` and maybe then something like that:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" th:with="view=${#httpServletRequest.getServletPath()}">
  <li th:classappend="${#strings.startsWith(view,'/home')? 'active' : ''}"><a href="#" th:href="@{/home}">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or you can use ControllerAdvice:

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = { MyController.class })
public class MyControllerAdvice {

  @ModelAttribute
  public void addAttributes(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
String activeTab = ... whatever
    model.addAttribute("active_tab", activeTab);
  }
}
```

There is one big disadvantage of using @ControllerAdvice. If you are planning to use Spring WebFlow to create multi-page forms (wizards) then it will not work because WebFlow does not use model attributes.

Comment: Thanks , it should be `th:with="path=${#httpServletRequest.getServletPath()}"` . Is it possible to judge by controller ?

Comment: oki, thx I have updated the answer additionally I used 'th:classappend' which is much better because it only adds the class to existing ones.

Comment: yes you can, you can create @ControllerAdvice and add property active_tab

Answer (score 0):

change this line `<nav class="..." th:fragment="header(activeTab)">`
to this
`<nav class="..." th:fragment="header(activeTab='activeTab')">`
it worked for me